# Node.js crypto create ecdh with the tron public address

Tags: node.js, cryptojs, ecdh

I am aiming for wallet address encryption, using the [TronWeb.createAccount()](https://developers.tron.network/docs/account), I fetch the public address for wallet in base58 and the private key as hex.

```
Sample Public Address: TPeGpPdJGQoNobV4SEjXLdrjefN3iCAAAA
Sample Private Key: 6B07B82D50B27171F35BF1DEAB14...
```

I am getting the keys using following code.

```js
const TronWeb = require('tronweb');
function createAccount() {
    try {
        const tronWeb = new TronWeb(fullNode, solidityNode, eventServer);
        return tronWeb.createAccount();

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

When I use the getPublicKey() method after setting the private key in bob.createECDH() the code works fine but in actual I will not have the utility of setPrivateKey() method for alice when I am on bob side. So I will have to pass the base58 public address instead of bob.getPublicKey() or alice.getPublicKey() on either side.

```js
const alice_secret = alice.computeSecret('HEX_PUBLIC_KEY','hex');
```

Following is the full code for encryption and decryption.

```js
const alice = crypto.createECDH('secp256k1');
const bob = crypto.createECDH('secp256k1');
bob.setPrivateKey("PRIVATE_KEY_FOR_BOB", "hex");
alice.setPrivateKey("PRIVATE_KEY_FOR_ALICE", "hex");

const alice_secret = alice.computeSecret(bob.getPublicKey());
console.log("alice's shared Key: " + alice_secret.toString('hex') + "\n");

var algo = 'aes-256-ecb', plainText = "Some secret to share bob";
var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algo, alice_secret)
var encrypted = cipher.update(plainText, 'utf8', 'hex')
encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
console.log("Encrypted: " + encrypted);

const bob_secret = bob.computeSecret(alice.getPublicKey());
console.log("bob's shared Key: " + bob_secret.toString('hex') + "\n");

var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algo, bob_secret)
var decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'hex', 'utf8')
decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
console.log("Decrypted: " + decrypted);

if (plainText == decrypted) {
    console.log("ECDH Success")
}
```

The output is expected when I use setPrivateKey() and then use getPublicKey()

```
alice's shared Key: 238c3eba08585a5cae1006710c79fe2de329545e9ca4c1ef719c53b55eb337b6
app.js:21 Encrypted: 44184052d9e205fd855aaf5f30b5f186c4bab88a5cfdce58d99cd8c696954c8dd5676807e6fe372fbe3ca5b230e54293
app.js:29 bob's shared Key: 238c3eba08585a5cae1006710c79fe2de329545e9ca4c1ef719c53b55eb337b6
app.js:35 Decrypted: QmdUuJDvgZ7EWEpJmEcFCoYwotn9CHyvK4qEhZs82AhZoQ
app.js:40 ECDH Success
```

When I convert the public key to hex using bs58 or any other package it says

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to translate Buffer to a EC_POINT
```

Is there a way to convert this public address and use it in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to study the ECDH supported key format and regenerate the keys according to new format to be able to fix this issue.
There were two formats of the public key that we can use to encrypt data.